# How to remove the text added by \addtocontents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, etoc

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}


\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page\par}

% The first TOC
\tableofcontents
\section{first part}
\subsection{first part}

% The second TOC
%%%% I don't want the text "Page" to appear in the second TOC %%%%
% What shall I do for this?
\tableofcontents
\section{second part}
\subsection{second part}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the way you're "supposed" to do it, but you could use a custom command instead of literal "Page", and then redefine the command later on. You'll have to add a `\protect` to keep it from expanding when the .toc file is written:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand{\Page}{\hfill Page\par}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\Page}

% The first TOC
\tableofcontents
\section{first part}
\subsection{first part}

% The second TOC
\renewcommand{\Page}{}
\tableofcontents
\section{second part}
\subsection{second part}

\end{document}
```

[image: toc with and without "page"]

Comment: Many thanks for this solution!! And, if there are ten items added by `\addtocontents`, and I want to remove one of them, doest that mean ten macros stored these items have to be defined?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you're doing, but probably not. You'd only have to use a macro for the entries or parts you want to be able to change. I'd probably have to know your real use case to be able to comment further.